# JQuery autocomplete drop down of valid values does not work on IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, jquery-autocomplete

Following info I found on another SO question, I have improved my autocomplete to display the list of available values when a field gets focus. This works perfectly well in Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE9.

I have created a code example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PEhdP/2/). It works if you open it with Firefox or Chrome, but does not work if you open it with IE9. Why?

Anyone has a solution to this issue?

**UPDATE**

[image: Description of the issue]

The above image is for FireFox. The list of available values is displayed when the cursor is set in the field. This list is not displayed when using IE9.

Comment: It works fine for me ... (in IE9) ... you don't provide a lot of detail about exactly *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pointy I have updated my question with a screen shot

Comment: The list is definitely displayed for me as soon as the text input gets focus. In IE9.

Comment: Ok. Very strange. It does not work for a friend of mine too. Really strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if` condition should like this, use `==` instead of using `===`

```
if (this.value == "") {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
}
```

==  is equal to(values only)

=== is exactly equal to (value and type)

---

EDIT

Just comment the `console.log(this.value);` then it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/PEhdP/4/

Answer (score -2):

`$(function()
            {
                var cache = {},
                lastXhr;
                $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
                    minLength: 2,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var term = request.term;
                        if ( term in cache ) {
                            response( cache[ term ] );
                            return;
                        }
                        lastXhr = $.getJSON( "search.php", request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                            cache[ term ] = data;
                            if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                                response( data );
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });`

//Please Try This One